# Sending messages to an asynchronous service, with transactions

Tags: spring, spring-transactions, spring-integration

I have a persistent, transactional queue containing messages I need to send over an asynchronous protocol. Each message needs to be sent in its own transaction, but the number of messages *in flight* at a given time precludes using *thread-per-message*, while throughput requirements preclude persisting intermediate states.

Looking at the code for `JmsTransactionManager`, I see it's using `TransactionSynchronizationManager`, which stores transaction resources in a `ThreadLocal`. So it seems that I'm going to need to implement a `PlatformTransactionManager` to somehow shepherd multiple transactions within a single thread. This *seems* a bit extreme...

Is there some arrangement of Spring Integration units that would obviate this complexity?
Should I rather be looking info JTA/XA?

Answer (score 1):

All of these queue-based channels in Spring Integration are storing messages in-memory only by default. When persistence is required, you can either provide a '`message-store`' attribute within the '`queue`' element to reference a persistent MessageStore implementation, or you can replace the local channel with one that is backed by a persistent broker, such as a JMS-backed channel or Channel Adapter. The latter option allows you to take advantage of any JMS provider's implementation for message persistence.

You can configure a Message Store for any `QueueChannel` by adding the message-store attribute as shown below.

Spring Integration provides support for the Message Store pattern by a) defining a `org.springframework.integration.store.MessageStore` strategy interface, b) providing several implementations of this interface, and c) exposing a message-store attribute on all components that have the capability to buffer messages so that you can inject any instance that implements the MessageStore interface.

My example uses the [JDBC Message Store](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#jdbc-message-store), but there are also several other options avaialble.

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${my.jdbc.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${my.jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${my.jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${my.jdbc.password}"/>
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="300000"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="60000"/>
    <property name="connectionProperties" value="SetBigStringTryClob=true;"/>
</bean>

<!-- The poller is needed by any of the QueueChannels -->
<integration:poller id="myPoller" fixed-rate="5000" default="true"/>

<!-- The MessageStore is needed to persist messages used by any of the QueueChannels -->
<int-jdbc:message-store id="myMessageStore" data-source="myDataSource" table-prefix="MY_INT_"/>

<!-- Main entry point into the process -->
<integration:gateway id="myGateway"
                     service-interface="com.mycompany.myproject.integration.gateways.myGateway"
                     default-request-channel="myGatewayChannel"
        />

<!-- Map the initial input channel to the first step, MyFirstService -->
<integration:channel id="myGatewayChannel">
    <integration:queue capacity="1000"/>
    <integration:queue message-store="myMessageStore" capacity="1000"/>
</integration:channel>

<!-- Step 1: My First Service -->
<integration:service-activator
        id="myFirstServiceActivator"
        input-channel="myGatewayChannel"
        output-channel="myNextChannel"
        ref="myFirstService"
        method="process"/>    

<!-- LONG running process. Setup asynchronous queue channel. -->
<integration:channel id="myNextChannel">
    <integration:queue capacity="1000"/>
    <integration:queue message-store="myMessageStore" capacity="1000"/>
</integration:channel>
```

Comment: While this is all true, as I stated, I don't want to persist intermediate state, or have a thread per message.